# Hard-code GeoPackage tables as either a model input or output

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

**Background:**

At 3.28.8 I've created a model whose first Algorithm is the *Field Calculator*.  I need its input to be a specific Geopackage table located on a local drive.  That is, I need to hard-code the table path/name into the Field Calculator rather than allowing the user to make a selection.

I have not found a way to do this. Here's what I've tried:

I select *Value* from the Input dropdown:

[image]

and then dropdown and click "Browse for Layer..."

[image]

Although this takes me to a menu tree where I can select the desired Geopackage table, the resulting layer name is appended with some sort of UUID string.  Not surprisingly, running the model with this input fails.

[image]

In addition to hard-coding the input, it would also be useful to hard-code the output as well.

**Question:** How to hard-code GeoPackage tables as either a model input or output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can hardcode the input geopackage. A geopackage is a database containing different layers (tables). So you have to specify the layername in your geopackage:

```
C:/path_to_geopackage/mygeopackage.gpkg|layername=my_layer
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect!  FWIW, I found that if there were spaces on either side of the pipe symbol, an error would occur.  Without the spaces, everything worked correctly.